Is there a correct way to say the number 1'000'000'000?
Many english speakers call 1'000'000'000 a billion. But that is mathematically wrong, since a million is 1'000'000 and bi means 2, so a billion is 1'000'000'000'000 (since 2*1'000'000 doesn't make sense, it has to be 1'000'000^2 or 1'000'000'000'000). Similar story with larger numbers.
Is there a better way? A correct way to say 1'000'000'000? Other than saying something like »Ten to the power of nine«.

It is one billion, whether or not it 'makes sense'. Historically in UK a billion was a million million, but now it is a thousand million, as USA. You can also say a thousand million. In general, people don't understand something expressed as a power.

@WeatherVane This is mathematical nonsens. Sorry. This is not and will never be a billion.

As I commented, is was the bi million million at one time. But not now, and it might seem nonsense, but that is what people say. Language is not logical.

@WeatherVane Just because people say that does not make it correct. I don't see why people defend that. Does bi not mean 2 or does million not mean 1'000'000? That is why there is the question: Is there a correct way to say that that people will understand and isn't cluncky to say.

In language, what is 'correct' is what most people say. Language isn't proscribed by a higher power. People will understand the non-clunky one billion.

@WeatherVane It is just simple math. That bi means 2 and million means 1'000'000 is arbitary, but since many languges use the latin meaning of this, a billion is 1'000'000'000. Either we have to say that bi doesn't mean 2, a million doesn't mean 1'000'000 (language part) or the math doesn't work out (math part).

Sorry, I have no idea why you are challenging language with maths.

This is like saying that calling a peanut a peanut is wrong, because it's a misnomer and not actually a pea or a nut. That does not mean it is wrong to call a peanut a peanut - whatever it actually is, it's called a peanut. The number 1,000,000,000 is called a billion - it's not wrong to call something by its name, whether or not that name appropriately describes or alludes to any characteristics of the item at all.

And sometimes just 1 can cause trouble with scales (long scale and short scale). Even with capitalization: Latin, English speakers.

@Lambie good point. One isn't 1 it is me.

@WeatherVane Does bi mean 2 or not? does million mean 1'000'000? If so, the rest is the result of math. Calling something onehoundertandone that is not 101 would also be wrong, even if everybody would do it, or not?

@NuclearHoagie Calling it a peanut is wrong. Because, as you said, it is not a nut.

@WeatherVane No, honey, it's the other one. :)

In modern English that number is referred to as one billion. In the past, in British English one billion had an additional 3 zeros (a million million or 1,000,000,000,000) but eventually the rest of the English speaking world adopted the American billion. Previously that number was either called one thousand million or  one milliard (which is now obsolete).

@Lambie mybad, it's I.

@BillyKerr Yes, we all know that english people refer to that as billion, that is not the question and that does not make it correct to say a billion.

You are flogging a dead horse. Although whether flogging refers to beating or selling is moot.

@WeatherVane Ok, back to the question: How would you say 1'000'000'000 without beeing mathematically wrong?

In this mathematics dictionary one billion is 1,000,000,000.

You've already been told other names for it.  I'm bored. Bye!

@WeatherVane Careful, there is trickery a-foot: beeing. Bzz.

@12431234123412341234123 If you ask in a language forum you're going to get a language answer. Imagine I went into a math forum and said something like "Give me an answer to 1 + 1, but not 2, because that is fewer characters than 1 + 1 so it doesn't make sense because the string length gets shorter. The answer must make logical sense in terms of string concatenation but must also be mathematically correct!"

@WeatherVane Yes same definition in the OED. If the OED says a billion is1,000,000,000 then it' is. So does Meriam Webster.

Having been a Jules Verne reader (in English translation) at the age of 9 (and often since), I am perfectly happy to call one followed by nine zeroes 'a milliard' but I think I would just get puzzled looks and grunts from most people I know.

@MichaelHarvey perhaps it is a billiard when you pocket it.

@WeatherVane - I haven't played that game for quite a while.

@12431234123412341234123 since a million is 1'000'000 and bi means 2 ... going by your argument, wouldn't a billion be 2'000'000, not 1'000'000'000'000?

@YonKuma I want a language answer: What better word is there that isn't mathematically wrong. I don't understand it, either you guys belive that when the wast majority says something it becomes correct or i completely missunderstand something. Please explain someone.

@jsotola Good point, but addition is not the only way to connect 2 numbers. In this case the meaning is a million to the power of 2 (Like in the vast majority of european languages excpet modern english). The expression 1'000'000 * 1'000'000 also has 2 millions in it (doesn't mean it is 2 times a million).

@WeatherVane Sorry, i don't understand. You you think math changes based on what a dictionary says?

@12431234123412341234123 The expression 1'000'000 * 1'000'000 also has 2 millions in it ... no, it has a million millions in it ... by your argument, a tricycle should have four wheels

@12431234123412341234123 once again, that number is one thousand million, which is mathematically correct. In English, it is also referred to as one billion. It's a commonly used word. What do you think the correct way to say it is, given that you insist everybody else is wrong?

@12431234123412341234123 The purpose of language is to communicate. The purpose of a Language Learner's help stack is to help people learning a language communicate more effectively. You've been given the answer that is the most in-line with helping you communicate effectively, and you've dismissed it. You've also dismissed answers that will be less effective at communication but still may be understood by a minority of people. All that leaves are objectively wrong answers: answers that won't communicate information successfully to anyone else in the world.

The number 10⁹ is called "one billion" in most dialects of English.
That is a fact, and you just have to accept it.  You can't argue logic, since natural language isn't based on logic.
Your notation for grouping digits is also wrong.  In written English, digits are not grouped, or grouped by (thin) spaces or commas, so the number "one billion" is written as  1000000000 or 1,000,000,000 or 1 000 000 000.
Historically "billion" doesn't mean million squared, it means "the second in a geometric series of numbers: million, billion, trillion, quadrillion..."    For mathematical purposes you should use digits and not words.

»Historically "billion" doesn't mean million squared, it means "the second in a geometric series of numbers: million, billion, trillion, quadrillion..."« Do you have a source for that? Since for the meaning of at second place, would you not normaly use the word secundus or second or something similar in latin based terms?

Using commas or points to group digits is a horrible idea. Since it is easy to mix them up with the decimal seperator. The space version is good but it makes it harder to avoid unwanted linebreaks.

Chuquet and De la Rosche seem to have defined the term first, in French in the 15th century Look them up. Different authors have used different defintions, but all agree that there is a sequence with first term "million"=10^6 and terms "billion", "trillion", "quadrillion" etc.  The formation of "billion" is by substituion of the first two letters of "million" with "bi"=2. The terms of this sequence form a geometric progression.  Different people have at different times used either 10^3 or 10^6 as the common ratio in this sequence.

But you are quite right to say that "bi" equals "two" because "billion" is the number 2 term in this sequence.  If you want to know more, please ask at [french.se]  since the word "billion" is a borrowing from French.

You could also say, that using a comma for a decimal separator is a horrible idea. Since it is easy to mix it up with the punctuation used for grouping.
